# Correct syntax for inheritDoc in phpDocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc, inheritdoc

What is the correct syntax for @inheritDoc in phpDocumentor if I just want to inherit all of the documentation from parent? Maybe more than one syntax is correct?

1. `@inheritDoc`
2. `{@inheritDoc}`
3. `@inheritdoc`
4. `{@inheritdoc}`

The documentation is pretty vague I think. PhpStorm seems to support all of them but maybe I'll have trouble generating the docs with some of the syntax?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A child element should be automatically inheriting pretty much everything from its parent docblock *without* needing this tag.  Otherwise, all your implementation methods would have to be documented all over again without gaining anything by the original interface's documentation.

Simply, an inherited element without a docblock **should** automatically inherit *everything* from its parent's docblock.

The `@inheritdoc` tag's sole purpose is to help you import **one** thing from the parent docblock -- that parent's Long Description.  The only reason the child should not already have this available is if the child went ahead and had its own docblock.  Now, the child *should* still be inheriting nearly everything from its parent docblock without having to duplicate it... **except** the parent's Long Description.  *If* the child docblock chose to have its own docblock for some reason, *and* you *still* want to inherit the parent's Long Description, then where you put `@inheritdoc` in the child docblock determines where that parent Long Description appears.  Thus, the child can have its own Short Description and Long Description, and still **also** include its parent's Long Description in a specified spot in relation to the child Long Description.  **This is the sole reason this tag was ever born** :-)

With regard to IDE autocompletion, I can't say that I've seen consistent behavior across IDEs when it comes to this tag.  Further, I've seen projects where the assumption is made that this tag **is the reason** that inherited information from parent docblocks even happens.

Comment: I think the answer is mostly there but you should clarify that you mean {@inheritDoc}. The braces clarify that it's inline and this only brings in the long desc like you said. See the note here about {@inheritdoc}, it's misuse, and the new @inheritDoc tag on its way https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/inheritance.html#the-inheritdoc-tag.

Comment: `@inheritDoc` is handy in legacy codebases to tell readers that the documentation is missing intentionally. Documentation generators don't need that but humans looking at the code in an editor / on Github do. (This is apparently [called out explicitly](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#61-making-inheritance-explicit-using-the-inheritdoc-tag) in the draft standard as well.)

Answer (score 5):

I know nothing about IDE support but the [documentation](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/inheritance.html#the-inheritdoc-tag) spells it as `{@inheritDoc}`.

Comment: the documentation also spell it as `{@inheritdoc}` https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.inlineinheritdoc.pkg.html

Comment: In addition to [docs.phpdoc.org](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/inheritance.html#the-inheritdoc-tag) documentation spelling it as `{@inheritDoc}`, it addresses the usage of this tag for explicitly replacing _all_ contents of the DocBlock with that of the parent/interface (see the red "important" paragraph), and distinguishes between the original inline `{@inheritDoc}` tag which includes the description of the parent, and a new/potential `@inheritDoc` tag, that replaces the whole content (and which is already being used in that way by some clients).

Comment: The hyperlink in the answer is dead/broken.